# How to run a background process in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a symfony commad that needes few minutes to be completed.  And i want to run it by a http request. The problem is that the server kills the command process just after sending response, he has a timeout.

i tried to use symfony process asynchronously But still not working ( i get always the timeout problem).

I dont want use the kernel.terminate event, since it is not a best practice.  Here is the code in my controller :

```
            $commandProcess=new Process('php  bin/console app:doSomeThing');
            $commandProcess->setWorkingDirectory('./../');
            $commandProcess->start();
            $commandProcess->setTimeout(50000000);
```

Any response will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `php-fpm` by any chance?

Comment: Have you tried to settimeout before starting the process?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @Med, i tried before starting the process, but still not work.

Comment: Thank you @N.B.  Unfortuntly we are using an openShift image and currently we dont have php-fpm installed on it. I will talk to the adminstrator to see if it possible to install it but i dont think that  is easy.

Comment: "_I dont want use the kernel.terminate event, since it is not a best practice_" Can you tell us why exactly?

Comment: Why you think it is a timeout problem? Can you show an output? Did you tried to use `/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/project/bin/console command` instead `php bin/console command`? php executable can be found using `PhpExecutableFinder` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to desibale the process output and add '&' after the command
Here the answer:

```
     new Process('php  bin/console app:dosomthing &');

    $commandProcess=new Process('php  bin/console app:dosomthing &');
    $commandProcess->setWorkingDirectory('./../');
    $commandProcess->disableOutput();
    $commandProcess->setTimeout(1800);
    $commandProcess->start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I write here the solution that has finally worked for me

First create a service:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;


class ProcessService {

public function __construct(
    private KernelInterface $appKernel
){ }

public function executeProcessAsync($processToExecute) {
    $rootDir = $this->appKernel->getProjectDir();
    $process = Process::fromShellCommandline($processToExecute . ' &');
    $process->setWorkingDirectory($rootDir);
    $process->disableOutput();
    $process->setTimeout(0);
    $process->start();
}
```

}

Then we use the service from a controller:

```
class MyController {

public function __construct(
    private ProcessService $procesService
){
public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
// (other stuff ...)

    $this->procesService->executeProcessAsync('php bin/console mycommands:command ');

    // (other stuff...)

}
}
```